# Change IFrame src from php after user login

Tags: php, html, iframe

So, first of all im pretty new to HTML/PHP/Javascript so bear with me.

I got the following on my index.html file

```
 ...
 <body>
     <div id="content">
          <iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" src="home.html" name="content_frame"/>
     </div>
 </body>
 ...
```

As you can see, it is a simple IFrame that contains another page. The other page, home.html, has a login form. After the user login I want to change the src of the IFrame above to another page. I just have no idea how to do that, I searched for a while but didn't get many results (i didn't really understand the ones I got, tbh).

The PHP login looks like this as of now:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

... //gets user/pass from mysql database, bla bla bla 

if($hash != $hash2) // Incorrect password.
{
    //go back to login page
    header('Location: ../index.html');

}else{ // Successful login.

    session_regenerate_id();
    $_SESSION['sess_user_id'] = $userData['id'];
    $_SESSION['sess_username'] = $userData['username'];
    session_write_close();

    //change iframe src to home page
    //???? how?
}
```

?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to do anything on your PHP login page. When user is logged in you are activating two session variables, $_SESSION['sess_user_id'], $_SESSION['sess_username'] . So you can just check if any of these two variable is set or not, then decide which iframe to load.

First rename your index.html to index.php so it can run php to make that decision, and start the session by adding following line at the top of the page:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

Then edit you current iframe line to following:

```
<?php if( isset($_SESSION['sess_user_id'] || isset($_SESSION['sess_username']) ) { ?>
    <iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" src="some-other-page.html" name="content_frame" />
<?php } else { ?>
        <iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" src="home.html" name="content_frame" />
<?php } ?>
```

This is the simplest approach.

Answer (score 0):

What I do on my website to check if a user is online I use this php code:

```
class Init {
  public static $logged_in = false;
  $session = intval($_SESSION['sess_user_id']);
      if(empty($session)){
            self::$logged_in = true;
      } else {
            self::$logged_in = false;
      }
}
```

And on the website with the iframe you could check if the user is logged in, if so show the home page, if not show the other page.

```
<?php  if(Init::$logged_in){ ?>
  <iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" src="nothome.html" name="content_frame"/>
<?php } else { ?>
  <iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" src="home.html" name="content_frame"/>
<?php } ?>
```